# Loading JSON from Postgres Column via jdbc

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a postgres table that I am loading data out of for a java application. One of my columns is of type JSON. The problem is JDBC ResultSet does not have a loader for Json. Is my best bet to use `resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME")` or is there another option?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To read from SQL using `ResultSet`? No other option (unless it's huge and defined as a CLOB).

To get JSON? *Yes.* You parse the JSON string you retrieved with `getString()`, using JSON parser of your choice, e.g. see this article: [Top 7 Open-Source JSON-Binding Providers Available Today](http://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/top-7-open-source-json-binding-providers-available-today.html)

Summary:

- [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome)
- [Google-Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)
- [JSON-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/)
- [Flexjson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/)
- [Json-io](https://code.google.com/p/json-io/)
- [Genson](http://owlike.github.io/genson/)
- [JSONiJ](https://bitbucket.org/jmarsden/jsonij/wiki/Home)

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't find another place where it was supported... Seemed like the kind of thing that would be implemented given it is a supported datatype in postgres

Comment: But it's not a supported datatype in Java or JDBC.

Comment: Came back across this now many moons later and realized the difference. Thanks.